# how to see backbone.js model data in firebug

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have created a model in backbone.js.

```
var Content = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // If you don't provide a Content, one will be provided for you.
  EMPTY: "empty Content...",

  // Ensure that each Content created has `content`.
  initialize: function() {

  }
});

 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          var content = new Content(data[i]);

        }
```

can i see the list of all model with data in firebug in watch , if yes then how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models are still simply Javascript variables.   In your code above you are just setting var content over and over again.

Making a wild guess here but I think you would want something like

`

```
ContentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Content,
    initialize: function() { }
});

my_contents = new ContentsCollection;

for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    my_contents.add(new Content(data[i]) );
}
```

`